# No input file specified with nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm getting "No input file specified." when I attempt to browse to the phpmyadmin domain, not sure what I'm doing wrong.. using both php-fpm and php-cgi, php-fpm is currently working another directory fine..Had to change the port number to 8888 since -fpm was already using 9000

http://pastebin.com/kdEckiL3

from nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name phpmyadmin.domain.com;
    access_log /home/fanboy/logs/phpmyadmin.access_log;
    error_log /home/fanboy/logs/phpmyadmin.error_log;

location / {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way will be relocate your "root" line out of your location block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name phpmyadmin.domain.com;
    access_log /home/fanboy/logs/phpmyadmin.access_log;
    error_log /home/fanboy/logs/phpmyadmin.error_log;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Apparently nginx server configuration some how missed the document root setting.

Got this idea from [Nginx Configuration Guide for PHP FastCGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample).

Comment: Awesome. This worked. Kudos!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

fastcgi.conf is redefining SCRIPT_FILENAME to $document_root$fastcgi_script_name.  If you set the root in the server (Just remove the "location / {" and matching }) and remove the SCRIPT_FILENAME line from your php location, it should work fine.